# Firing Command from Buttons within Combobox using MVVM Light

Tags: wpf, button, mvvm, combobox, command

I am having a problem with a custom ComboxBox firing events.  The idea is to have the combobox bound to a collection of items with an Edit and Delete button in-line with each item.  I can make the click event work using code-behind, but the command binding seems to do nothing.

```
    <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" 
                                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                <Button Content="Edit" 
                                        Margin="0,0,5,0" 
                                        Command="{Binding EditConnectionCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding ID}"/>
                                <Button Content="Delete"
                                        Command="{Binding DeleteConnectionCommand}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding ID}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
                    <CompositeCollection>
                        <ComboBoxItem IsEnabled="False" Visibility="Collapsed">Select a database connection...</ComboBoxItem>
                        <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource ConnectionsBridge}}" />
                        <ComboBoxItem>...New Connection...</ComboBoxItem>
                    </CompositeCollection>
                </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
            </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binding looks for the commands in the items, not in the ViewModel of the window.
To change this, fix your binding like this:

```
{Binding ElementName=root, Path=DataContext.EditConnectionCommand}
```

For this to work, you need to add `Name="root"` to your `UserControl` or `Window`.